# Can Bloomberg run again in the future, or is the 3-term limit absolute?

Tags: united-states, election-requirements, new-york-city, michael-bloomberg

What I mean is, are Mayors of NYC limited to three *consecutive* terms, or three terms in their lifetime? I couldn't find any answer to this question anywhere.

Could Bloomberg run again in another 4 years?

Comment: go back in time 4 years ago and ask: `"can Bloomberg run again in the future, or is the 2-term limit absolute?"`

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the consecutive term limit is back down to two terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://nypost.com/2010/08/12/term-limits-will-land-on-city-ballot-in-nov/) New York Post, the term-limit ban is only on consecutive terms.  The New York Times corroborated this in another article, but I can't seem to find it now. :)

As such, Mayor Bloomberg could run again in 4 years, if he chose.

Comment: A bit like Putin...

Comment: @davblayn - [Yup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gncW1zqMFgs) (and the [original russian version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKTR0qWlFP0)). And [of course](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D0%A3%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%B8&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.53217764,d.dmg,pv.xjs.s.en_US.6PYzwk9faGo.O&biw=1600&bih=753&dpr=1.2&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=-9dEUvjvC4fa4AP8woHwDg) the obligatory [Dobby Like Putin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z38ML7ba9I)

Comment: Americans, think the rest of the world uses the same system as they do and if it's different it must be undemocratic.